# Reinstalling more

Tags: linux-mint, more

I messed up and rewrote `/usr/bin/more` with some gibberish. Is there a way to reinstall only `more`? Or in which package can I find the `more` command?

Comment: I've not used 'more' on Linux in decades. Try 'less'. BTW you can get the package name using `dpkg-query -S /path/to/file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It was in `util-linux` package.
`apt-get install --reinstall util-linux` solved the issue.

Comment: Or the more modern `apt reinstall util-linux` or the good old `aptitude reinstall util-linux` (or press `L` on that package in `aptitude`)